# How to make 2 varible add side by side?(Java) 2+2=22

Tags: java, eclipse

int x= 2;

int y= 2;

int z= (?);

System.out.println(z);

I want it to print 22 instead of 4

Comment: `System.out.println(x + "" + y);`. I think you can also put the empty string at the start, as in, `"" + x + y`.

Comment: `int z = x * 10 + y`;

Comment: use string concatination

Comment: `int z = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(x) + y);`

Comment: *Why* do you want that? Why do you want to use integers instead of strings or characters? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use them as strings and parse it

```
    String s=x+""+Y;
    Integer.parseInt(s);
```